# Restore firebird database just from fdb file

Tags: firebird, database-restore

Had a webserver crash yesterday and had to reinstall system (Ubuntu)..99% of the data/application restores were just fine as I use mysql and have proper backups, however also have 2 firebird databases which were unfortunatelly not backuped using gbak and I have only the fdb files available.

Is there any way to restore Firebird database (or mine data into sql scripts etc..) just from the fdb files?

The problem is a big pain and quite urgent, so thanks for any suggestions (gfix etc does not work..all attempts to connect or do anything return "is not a valid database" error..).

Comment: which version of firebird ? which user you use for accessing your database ?

Answer (score 4):

fdb is the database file : so you don't have to restore it.

diagnose and repair :

- [Diagnosing and Repairing InterBase Database Corruption](https://web.archive.org/web/20071021040643/http://ibphoenix.com:80/main.nfs?a=ibphoenix&page=ibp_db_corr)
- [How To Analyse and Repair a Corrupted Database](https://www.ibphoenix.com/articles/art-00000005)